# Using Fluent NHibernate Persistence Tester Tool with Object that has encrypted Password field

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

First of all: I am completely new to Fluent ***and*** NHibernate.

I have a User object that contains a password field.  When setting that field  the value gets encrypted.  Now I try to use the

```
new PersistenceSpecification<User>(session)
    ...
    .CheckProperty(p => p.Password, "secret")
    ...
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

persistence checker tool.  The problem I am facing is the handling of the password field.  The debugger told me that the tool calls the Password field setter multiple times.  The first time with the cleartext password "secret".  The following times with the encrypted versions ending up with encrypting my password multiple times.

Any idea how to cope with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
NHibernate has to set the password on the user after it loaded it from db and when you use the standard

```
Map(user => user.Password);
```

it will use the property to set the db-value

```
Map(user => user.Password).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

prevents this then

Comment: Tried it - does not work.  'Password' is a property.  The backing fields name is _password (a string) which is declared private.  When simply adding ".Access.Field()" to my mapping generates an exception telling me that a field named 'Property' can't be found - which is true, the fields name is _property.

Comment: When changing to

Map(user => user._password).Access.Field();

the compiler complains that _password is not accessible.

When setting access level of _password to 'internal' or 'public' NHibernate complains at runtime with an exception stating that '_password' should not be 'internal' nor 'public'.

What now?

Comment: @Andreas with the additional info, see my edit. Leave _password private, it should only be accessible through the Property.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to use a setter method to set your password, for example

```
public virtual void UpdatePassword(string newPassword)
{
    string hashedPassword = HashPassword(newPassword);
    _password = hashedPassword;
}
```

This way your hash/encryption logic is separate from your property setter. In your PersistenceSpecification test you will then be testing the saving/getting of the encrypted text.

If you need to decrypt the password use a getter method to get the decrypted password (the `Password` property will contain the encrypted text).

```
public virtual string GetPasswordDecrypted()
{
    ...
}
```

As a side note, unless you have a good reason it will be better to hash the password than encrypt it.